# Android Browser for 1.6 and above not scrolling

Tags: android, html, css

I have a small frame on my site which has an 'overflow' attribute. All of the browsers except Android's allows me to scroll that small frame inside my website.

Am I missing something that I should declare inside CSS for Android Browsers?

Comment: I'm actually surprised that even opera allows that basic scrolling, tbh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I am assuming this is in a WebView Activity:** You will need to add a scroller within your HTML.  I use something like [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll).  This is byfar the best one out there and give the best performance.

Comment: hmm. there's no other workaround around this? i'm trying to avoid using hacks to just hack my way through so the user can scroll.